# ZIP Archives downloaded from Next.js API route are corrupted

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js, zip

I am trying to implement the download of a ZIP archive from server using Next.js, axios and js-file-download. However, when I try to open the downloaded archive, an error pops up saying that the archive is corrupted.

I am positive that the archive on the server is valid, so the problem is in the transfer to the client.

Also, if I try to download another file type (for example a .txt file), it works.

This is the server code, in /pages/api/assignments/[assignmentId]/students/index.tsx:

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {

    const assignmentId = req.query.assignmentId as string;
    
    const assignment = // here I get assignment from database

    switch(req.method) {
        case('GET'):
            const fileNames = assignment.fileUploads.map((fileUpload: AssignmentFileUpload) => fileUpload.fileName);

            const archivePath = `./resources/assignment_archives/${assignmentId}.zip`;
            
            // --- RELEVANT CODE STARTS HERE ---

            const archiveReadStream = fs.createReadStream(archivePath);

            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
                'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${assignment.title}.zip`
            });

            archiveReadStream.pipe(res);
    }
}
```

And this is the code on the client side:

```
const handleDownload = async (event: any) => {
    axios.get(`/api/assignments/${assignment.id}/students`, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/zip'
        }
    })
    .then((res) => {
        fileDownload(res.data, `${assignment.title}.zip`) // function imported from js-file-download
    });
}
```

I have already tried fiddling with headers, but nothing worked.